# Why is running localedef not creating my new locale in /etc/locale.gen?

Tags: environment-variables, locale

I am trying to create a new system locale. I have studied the directions at [Unix Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136920/set-custom-locales-in-gnome3-on-fedora-20) and at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653008/how-to-create-a-new-system-locale) but my attempts to get my environment variable into `/etc/locale.gen` have been unsuccessful.

I have created my environment variable according to [Sourceware](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=localedata/locales;hb=HEAD) and copied it into `/usr/share/i18n/locales`. (All I'm really doing is using en_US and changing the LC_TIME variable to use en_DK, so I copied the LC_TIME portion of en_DK into en_US and I am trying to make this into a new variable so that is lasts through updates. Changing the LC_TIME portion within the en_US file is not working because updates often reset it back to its original state).

Let's call my new variable en_US@XX. After I copied my variable, running `ls /usr/share/i18n/locales` shows my new variable in the listing.

Now I run `sudo localedef -i en_US@XX --quiet -f UTF-8 en_US@XX.UTF-8` and nothing is reported by bash leading me to believe everything was successfully done. But when I `cat /etc/locale.gen | less` my variable is not present. I have also tried command `sudo localedef -i en_US@XX -c -f UTF-8 en_US@XX.UTF-8` but this doesn't work either.

If I can just get my variable into `/etc/locale.gen`, then I can run `sudo locale-gen` and I should be good.

So how do I get my variable to appear in `/etc/locale.gen`? Am I misunderstanding what `localedef` is supposed to be doing? Don't I need to get my variable into `/etc/locale.gen` to be able to generate it for system use?

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to have missed is adding you custom locale to

```
/usr/local/share/i18n/SUPPORTED
```

with the line

```
en_US@XX UTF-8
```

Then a simple `sudo locale-gen` should do what you want.