# How to change Date language to English while using a different Format?

Tags: settings, language-support, system-settings, date

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with Language set to English (US) and Formats set to Deutschland. Everything works fine, except for the name of months in dates, e.g.

```
drwxrwxrwt 2 root  root  4,0K Mär 24 07:47 .X11-unix/
drwxrwxrwt 2 root  root  4,0K Mär 24 07:47 .XIM-unix/
```

I'd like to keep using English as a system-wide Language, with the local Formats, but without the nonsense of having non-English words here and there. How can I do it?

Comment: Not easy: you probably would need to create a custom locale: https://askubuntu.com/questions/653008/how-to-create-a-new-system-locale

Comment: Very useful link, thanks. Would you like to make your comment into an answer?

Comment: I cannot provide sufficient specifics to turn this into an answer that is useful to others. I suggest, if you manage to achieve your goal, that you describe how you proceeded in an answer to your own question, which you also can accept. This is perfectly acceptable on this site and will help many readers.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by switching to English (UK) language with United Kingdom formats, which already provides a decent experience, i.e. 24-hours clock, metric system, etc.