# Change default date format

Tags: server, locale, date

I've been trying to change the default date format since past few days.

**Current format:-**

```
$date
Mon Aug 20 14:14:43 IST 2018
```

**Expected format:-**

```
$date
Monday August 20 14:14:43 IST 2018
```

**Current locale**

```
$locale

LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=en_IN
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN"
LC_TIME=en_DK
LC_COLLATE="en_IN"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN"
LC_PAPER="en_IN"
LC_NAME="en_IN"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN"
LC_ALL=
```

**LC_TIME** section in **/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_DK**

```
% date formats following ISO 8601-1988
d_t_fmt  "<U0025><U0059><U002D><U0025><U006D><U002D><U0025><U0064><U0054><U0025><U0054><U0020><U0025><U005A>"
d_fmt    "<U0025><U0059><U002D><U0025><U006D><U002D><U0025><U0064>"
t_fmt    "<U0025><U0054>"
am_pm    "";""
t_fmt_ampm  ""

% Appropriate date representation (date(1))   "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
date_fmt    "<U0025><U0061><U0020><U0025><U0062><U0020><U0025><U0065>/
<U0020><U0025><U0048><U003A><U0025><U004D><U003A><U0025><U0053><U0020>/
<U0025><U005A><U0020><U0025><U0059>"
```

I have referred [this tutorial](https://ccollins.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/how-to-change-date-formats-on-ubuntu/) which I have come across to be the best and lengthy enough to be clear.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 stretch.
I need to modify this **en_DK** file or create a custom locale that suits my need. 
Although there are several workarounds like creating aliases. But I prefer to know what is going wrong.

Comment: Do you ask how to create a custom locale? In that case it's a duplicate of for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/21316/how-can-i-customize-a-system-locale

Comment: No.. It is not about creating custom locale.. But, I Need to modify the existing locale and recompile it with LC_TIME section changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really recommend to use

```
date +'%A %B %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
```

instead somehow. Creating a custom locale for the purpose feels like overdoing it.

*Edit:*

An option might be to

- edit `date_fmt` in the `en_DK` locale definition file and replace `<U0061>` and `<U0062>` with `<U0041>` respective `<U0042>`
- run the command `sudo locale-gen en_DK.UTF-8`

You should also set `en_DK.UTF_8` for `LC_TIME`, not `en_DK` (the latter enables latin1 encoding).

Comment: Yes.. But there is a 3rd party library which is relied upon `date` output. That's y I need to change the locale accordingly

Comment: @Goron: Please see edited answer.

Comment: @Goron Please add this important detail to your question.

Comment: How do i set `LC_TIME` to `en_DK.UTF-8`?.. I tried to `export LC_TIME="en_DK.UTF-8"` also added `LC_TIME="en_DK.UTF-8"`  in `/etc/environment` .. logged out and logged in. Still it is `en_DK` .

Comment: @Goron: Where did you set it to `en_DK`? Change it there. :)